# Reading eml file using R

Tags: r, email, nlp, tm

I cant read emails in R. I was unziping the file and then i was catching out the files that i want to work on it this mean:

```
data2 <- data[grep(".eml", data, fixed=T)]
```

I was using `library(tm.plugin.mail)` 
to read this eml files but is not really working 
`readMail(DateFormat = "%d %B %Y %H:%M:%S")`, 
`newsgroup <- system.file("data2","eml", package = "tm.plugin.mail")`,

```
text <- Corpus(VectorSource(data2), readerControl = list(reader = readMail))]
```

the code is not reading the texts of emails. I need the text of this emails for NLP.
Ps: there are many email that i want to read called data2.
I will appreciate any help